# Get pixel boundary coordinates from binary image in Python (not edges)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, polygon, scikit-image

I have a binary image containing a single contiguous blob, with no holes. I would like create a polygon object based on the exterior edges of the edge pixels. I know how to get the edge pixels themselves, but I want the actual coordinates of the pixel boundaries, sorted clockwise or counter-clockwise. All of the pixels have integer coordinates.

For example, say I have a single pixel at (2,2). The vertices of the polygon would be:
(2.5, 2.5)
(2.5, 1.5)
(1.5, 1.5)
(1.5, 2.5)
(2.5, 2.5)

Is there an exact, non-approximate way to do this? Preferably in Python?

Comment: You add/subtract 0.5 with each coordinate, "boxing" the 2x2 cominations.  Where are you stuck with this?

Comment: You're saying, add up the occurrences of all corners across all pixels, and keep those that have an odd number? That's pretty elegant. Then how do I order the leftover vertices? I'm not sure what boxing the combinations means.

Comment: No, I missed a phrase in your description.  Sorting points in clock order is solved in many places on line; look for "shape" algorithms in your research.  These will also give you routines and steps for finding the bounding box (trivial), the points of the convex container, or the edges or either.

Comment: I ran into this same problem today. I don't have an answer, but assuming you already know how to get the perimeter pixels in order (I use opencv's findContours), one way to get _closer_ to the border is to resample your blob image at higher resolution. Unfortunately this can be expensive, and it won't get you to the edges of the original pixels so it's not a good idea. But it's the only one I could think of immediately.

Comment: Another tip to help determine the set of pixel corners that should be in the final polygon: connect the pixel centers (again, assumes you know how to get perimeter), then remove all pixel corner coordinates that are inside the pixel-center polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is the approach that I implemented:

1. multiply all pixel coordinates by 10, so that we'll only deal with integers.
2. For each pixel, generate the 4 corners by adding +/- 5. For example, for (20,20), the corners are (25, 25) (25, 15) (15, 15) (15, 25) (25, 25). And store all the corners in a list.
3. Count the occurrences of each corner. If the count is odd, it is a corner to the blob. Making the coordinates integers makes this step easy. Counting floats has issues.
4. Divide the blob corner coordinates by 10, getting back the original resolution.
5. Sort the corners clockwise using a standard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

See example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageChops
import math

a = [['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
      ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
      ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
      ['.','#','#','#','.','.','.'],
      ['.','#','#','#','.','.','.'],
      ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.']]      

sz=(len(a[0]), len(a))
flat_list = [j=='.' for i in a for j in i]
image=Image.new('1', sz)
image.putdata(flat_list)
contour=ImageChops.difference(image, image.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3)))
contour_list=list(contour.getdata())
points=[divmod(i,sz[0]) for i in range(len(contour_list)) if contour_list[i]]
points_x,points_y=zip(*points)
avg=lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)
mean_x=avg(points_x)
mean_y=avg(points_y)
phase=[(math.atan2(points_y[i]-mean_y, points_x[i]-mean_x),i) \
       for i in range(len(points))] 
phase.sort()
for i in range(len(points)):
    print(*points[phase[i][1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but this code finds the pixels that border the '#'. I want the coordinates of the contour that divides the '#' from the border, which should have values of 0.5 in them.